# Visual Basic - YYYYMMDD HH:MM:SS:MS to

Tags: vba, excel

I have a Visual Basic script to sort out data from one sheet to another, the only problem is that column B contains date and time in the format of: "**YYYYMMDD HH:MM:SS:???**" as in 20160901 09:36:18:963

And after quite some time spent on google and stackoverflow I haven't found any working solution. I want all my data in columns A, B and C to be sorted after date, longest ago in the top, and the most recent one in the bottom.

Column A and B are then going to be put in to a graph but that is for later.

So in conclusion, I need help both changing my **YYYYMMDD HH:MM:SS:???** as in 20160901 09:36:18:963 into a date format (excel did not seem to recognize it as a date) and also sort the data after date.

Thank in advance!

This is the script as of now:

```
 Sub tjabo_script()
Dim ArtikelNummer As Variant
Dim NewSheet As Worksheet
Dim RowCount As Long
Dim i As Long, x As Long
Dim check_value As Range
ArtikelNummer = InputBox("Skriv in artikelnummer", "Artikelsortering")
Set NewSheet = Sheets.Add(After:=Sheets(Worksheets.Count), Count:=1, Type:=xlWorksheet)
NewSheet.Name = ArtikelNummer

x = 2 'This is the next empty row on NewSheet.
With Worksheets("Data")
    RowCount = .Cells(.Cells.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
    For i = 1 To RowCount
        If .Cells(i, 2) = Val(ArtikelNummer) Then
            .Cells(i, 2).Columns("D:D").Copy Destination:= _
                NewSheet.Cells(x, 1)
            .Cells(i, 2).Columns("N:N").Copy Destination:= _
                NewSheet.Cells(x, 2)
            .Cells(i, 2).Columns("C:C").Copy Destination:= _
                NewSheet.Cells(x, 3)
            x = x + 1
        End If
    Next i
End With
    Application.Worksheets(ArtikelNummer).Range("A1") = "LagerSaldo"
    Application.Worksheets(ArtikelNummer).Range("B1") = "Datum/Tid"
    Application.Worksheets(ArtikelNummer).Range("C1") = "Antal (+/-)"
End Sub
```

Comment: What's your script? Can you also post some sample data? (Copy/paste is preferred over a screenshot).

Comment: did you try Formatting the columns as dates?

Comment: use this formula in an empty column.  `=--SUBSTITUTE(REPLACE(REPLACE(B1,7,0,"-"),5,0,"-"),":",".",3)` And copy down.  Then format those new cells like you want.  `yyyymmdd hh:mm:ss.000`

Comment: Please read the HELP pages for information as to [How to Ask a Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask); and also [How to Provide an Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @ScottCraner Thank you! The problem is I want that function in my vb-script. Do you know any quick solution to "translate" it into visual basic?

Comment: `Worksheets(ArtikelNummer).[B:B] = [Index(IFERROR(--SUBSTITUTE(REPLACE(REPLACE(B:B,7,0,"-"),5,0,"-"),":",".",3),""),)]`

Comment: Thank you, however, now it says valueerror on each and everyone of them, and they all output #######

Here is an example of the date/times:
In one cell it says: 20160901 09:36:18:963

Could it be the 963 at the end that is messing it up?

Comment: Okey, so now I got that one to work @ScottCraner , however, the dates becomes weird formats, such as 1570584 which is imvalid. And also, the dates get some spaces meaning some rows are empty in column B and below all the data there are some random rows where other variations appear such as 1570604 in column B (date/time)

Answer (score 0):

Here's my approach. I'm assuming an example timestamp is something like `20161017 12:12:12:999` you are trying to a Date.

I made a simple UDF to change a string into a Date. From here once you have the date's value you can display it anyway you wish.

**Code**

```
Public Sub Example()
    ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Value = FormatAsDate("20161001 12:12:12:999")
End Sub

Function FormatAsDate(ByVal StrIn As String) As Date
    StrIn = Trim(StrIn)

    FormatAsDate = CDate(Left(StrIn, 4) & "/" & _
                   Mid(StrIn, 5, 2) & "/" & _
                   Mid(StrIn, 7, 2) & _
                   Mid(StrIn, 9, 9))
End Function
```

**Output**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

With sample data in **A1** like:

[image]

It is not possible to get VBA to handle the *millisecond* part if the VBA variable is of `Dim'ed` as a  `Date`.  It is better to use a `Double` variable.  Here a fragment of sample code:

```
Sub DateEquivalent()
    Dim dD As Double, s As String
    Dim d1 As Double, d2 As Double

    s1 = Range("A1").Text
    Mid(s1, 18, 1) = "."
    ary = Split(s1, " ")

    d1 = CDbl(DateSerial(Left(ary(0), 4), Mid(ary(0), 5, 2), Right(ary(0), 2)))
    s1 = "Timevalue(""" & ary(1) & """)"
    dD = d1 + Evaluate(s1)

    MsgBox d1 & vbCrLf & dD
End Sub
```

Note we convert that last colon into a period by using *Mid()*.  That is to make life easier for the worksheet *TIMEVALUE()* function:

[image]

The next step would be to modify this short macro to replace each "pseudo-date" with the equivalent `Double` variable.
Once you have `Double` variables, sorting is simple.